# Рывки объекта при быстром движении Unity

Tags: unity3d

Объект движется на wheel collider'ах, при наборе скорости больше 10 единиц в секунду, объект начинается двигаться рывками, убрав вертикальную синхронизацию и ограничив число кадров до 50, получилось снизить кол-во фризов, но все же они остались. Т.к. объект движется на вилах, расставить time.deltaTime не получится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте уменьшить интервал обновления физики в настройках проекта в [Time Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html). Вполне возможно, что при определенной скорости ваш объект передвигается слишком быстро, чтобы физика успевала корректно обрабатывать эти перемещения. Вам нужно изменить величину `Fixed Timestep`, от которой зависит частота обновления, так же на нее будет завязано с какой частотой у вас будет вызываться метод `FixedUpdate()` в ваших скриптах. Немного подробней об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TimeFrameManagement.html).

P.S. Если ваша проблема действительно заключается в физике, то изменение количества FPS не сильно вам поможет, так как физика в Unity работает отдельным потоком и обновляется по отдельному таймеру с фиксированным шагом, в отличии от графики.

Comment: при увеличении значения рывки увеличиваются, а при уменьшении - уменьшаются, но физика заметно начинает страдать, получается нужно упростить физику движения объекта?

Comment: @skDYLAN при уменьшении - точность физической симуляции увеличивается, в силу чего, некоторые силы/препятствия, которыми вы пренебрегали могут оказывать видимый эффект. Не зная точно вашей симуляции сложно сказать, что не так.

Comment: корень проблемы найден, как смешно бы это не звучало, но проблемой была камера, а точнее скрипт которые держит в фокусе камеры объект, обрабатывалась в методе LateUpdate, при переносе её в FixedUpdate проблема была устранена. Все таки зацепкой было то, что в сцене все нормально, а в игровом режиме нет

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена!
Использовал такой код:

```
Vector3 newPose = startPos - Input.mousePosition;
            startPos = Input.mousePosition;

            Vector3    newPose1 = new Vector3(newPose.x, 0, 0);

            Vector3 moveforce = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(newPose1, clampDelta);
            Vector3 back = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0, 0);
            rb.AddForce(-moveforce * 0.3f - back/1.1f , ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```